# Apply function to masked numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, mask

I've got an image as numpy array and a mask for image.

```
from scipy.misc import face

img = face(gray=True)
mask = img > 250
```

How can I apply function to all masked elements?

```
def foo(x):
    return int(x*0.5)
```

Comment: Actually function should return random value in range (0, 255) for every cell under mask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that specific function, few approaches could be listed.

**Approach #1 :** You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) for in-place setting -

```
img[mask] = (img[mask]*0.5).astype(int)
```

**Approach #2 :** You can also use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for a possibly more intuitive solution -

```
img_out = np.where(mask,(img*0.5).astype(int),img)
```

With that `np.where` that has a syntax of `np.where(mask,A,B)`, we are choosing between two equal shaped arrays `A` and `B` to produce a new array of the same shape as `A` and `B`. The selection is made based upon the elements in `mask`, which is again of the same shape as `A` and `B`. Thus for every `True` element in `mask`, we select `A`, otherwise     `B`. Translating this to our case, `A` would be `(img*0.5).astype(int)` and `B` is `img`.

**Approach #3 :** There's a built-in [`np.putmask`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html) that seems to be the closest for this exact task and could be used to do in-place setting, like so -

```
np.putmask(img, mask, (img*0.5).astype('uint8'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions! But how do I applied them to other function? Suppose, I need to generate random pixels instead of all masked cells. If I use these methods it will assign one value to all mask

Comment: Ok, I got it. At first I generate noisy image the same size as `img` and then I merge them by mask `ans = np.where(mask, noisy_template, img)`

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova Ah I got your question now! :) So yes, you can generate noisy_template with `noisy_template = np.random.randint(0,255,img.shape).astype('uint8')`.