# Invert binary NumPy array using a mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a binary N-by-N (N~=200) NumPy array populated with zeroes and ones. I would like to apply a Boolean mask and 'swap' the values that correspond to `True` in the mask, so for example if I had:

```
arr = np.array([0,0,1,1],
               [0,0,1,1],
               [0,0,1,1],
               [0,0,1,1])
mask = np.array([True,False,True,False],
                [True,False,True,False],
                [True,False,True,False],
                [True,False,True,False],
```

I would like the resulting array to be:

```
arr_new = np.array([1,0,0,1],
                   [1,0,0,1],
                   [1,0,0,1],
                   [1,0,0,1])
```

I started this by initially creating a function `swap_cell` that swaps between the values, and then followed the approaches in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421913/apply-function-to-masked-numpy-array).

```
def swap_cell(x):
    if x == 1.0:
        return 0.0
    elif x == 0.0:
        return 1.0

arr_new = np.where(mask,swap_cell(arr),arr)
```

This code returns `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`, which I understand is because of the 'if' statement in my `swap_cell()` function. I know there must be a much more pythonic way to accomplish this, but I thought this might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you interpret the first (0,1) array as a boolean array, then you are doing the [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation of each entry in the first array with each entry of the second array.

Therefore, you can do this with the numpy function np.logical_xor() as follows:

```
arr = np.array([[0,0,1,1],
                [0,0,1,1],
                [0,0,1,1],
                [0,0,1,1]])
mask = np.array([[True,False,True,False],
                 [True,False,True,False],
                 [True,False,True,False],
                 [True,False,True,False]])

np.array(np.logical_xor(arr, mask), dtype=int)
```

which returns

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Alternatively: `(mask!=arr).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be to subtract `1` and take the absolute value:

```
def swap(x):
    return np.abs(x - 1)
```

Since this is able to operate on the entire array, you can apply the mask, pass the masked array to `swap`, and assign the returned value to the masked elements:

```
arr = np.array([[0,0,1,1],
               [0,0,1,1],
               [0,0,1,1],
               [0,0,1,1]])
mask = np.array([[True,False,True,False],
                [True,False,True,False],
                [True,False,True,False],
                [True,False,True,False]])

arr[mask] = swap(arr[mask])
```

which results in your expected array:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Another approach would be to convert the `dtype` to `bool`, then invert the array, and finally restore the original `dtype`:

```
def swap(x):
    return (~x.astype(bool)).astype(x.dtype)
```